# I can't get the data

Tags: java, android

I can't get the data from a database.
Can you help me, please?

**Error Log :**

> 1-10091/com.example.dogruprint.dogruprint2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, u_name, u_pass FROM
>   users
>                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>
> > Method)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
> >                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
> >                     at com.example.dogruprint.dogruprint2.Database.getThat(Database.java:123)
> >                     at com.example.dogruprint.dogruprint2.siparisekle$2.onClick(siparisekle.java:113)
> >                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
> >                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
> >                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
> >                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> >                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> >                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
> >                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> >                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
> >                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
> >                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**DATABASE.java**

```
package com.example.dogruprint.dogruprint2;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Database {


    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "u_name";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "u_pass";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "app";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "users";
    private static final int version = 1;


    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase;


    public Database(Context context) {

        ourContext = context;

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        return writableDatabase;
    }




    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        public DBHelper(Context context)

        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


/*

            final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
                    + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR(255) , "
                    + KEY_PASS + " VARCHAR(255) ,"
                   ;

*/


            String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID +
                    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PASS + " TEXT"
                    + ");";



        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DB_TABLE);


        }


    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {


        ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);

        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;


    }

    public Database close() {

        ourHelper.close();
        return this;


    }

    public void addThat(String name, String pass) {


        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_PASS, pass);
        ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);


    }

    public String getThat()
    {
        String[] colomns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PASS};

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE,colomns,null,null,null,null,null);
        int İROW = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int İNAME= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int İPASS = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASS);

        String result = "";

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + "name" + c.getString(İNAME) + "pass" + c.getString(İPASS)+"\n";


        }



        return result;
    }
}
```

**siparisekle.java**

```
package com.example.dogruprint.dogruprint2;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static android.R.*;


public class siparisekle extends Activity {



    private AutoCompleteTextView act1, act2, act3;

    private  EditText edittxt1;

    EditText etName,etPass;
    TextView tvResult;
    Button bSave;
    Button bShow;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_siparisekle);

        final Database db = new Database(this);




        install_elements();





        bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean ok = true;
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

                try {
                    db.open();
                    db.addThat(name, pass);
                    tvResult.setText(name + "Eklendi");
                    db.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ok = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tvResult.setText("Sorun var");


                } finally {

                    if (ok) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(siparisekle.this);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(siparisekle.this);
                        tv.setText("BASARILI");
                        d.setTitle("Sonuç");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();


                    }

                }


            }
        });

        bShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)


            {
                try {
                    db.open();
                    String data = db.getThat();
                    tvResult.setText(data);
                    db.close();


                } catch (SQLException e)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Çağırmada Bir Sorun Oluştu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });






}
protected void install_elements()
{

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
    tvResult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    bSave= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
    bShow= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShow);

}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception message says this:

> no such table: users (code 1) while compiling "SELECT _id, u_name, u_pass FROM users"

It is looking for a table called "users" in the database, but it can't find one!

Either you haven't set up your database correctly (e.g. you haven't created the tables) or the schema (e.g. table names) for your database doesn't match what the application requires.

---

In fact, look at your `onCreate` method.  All it is doing is creating and throwing away a string containing some SQL.  You need to execute it ....

Answer (score 0):

You really need to execute your table creation:

```
String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID +
    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";

db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
```

You also need to call your `onCreate()` method inside your `onUpgrade()` method

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DB_TABLE);

    onCreate(db);
}
```